# Perl read file error

Tags: perl, file-io

I have to read a big (BIG) file in memory, line by line, using perl.
In case of some error, function open() does return false and $! is set to the system error.
But, if I get some errors *reading* the file?
I use this code:

```
open(STATISTICS, "<" . $statisticsFile) or die "Can't open statistics file $statisticsFile ($!)";
while (<STATISTICS>) {
  my $line = $_;
  ...
}
close($STATISTICS);
```

Any hint?

Comment: Any read error: say disk catches fire before finishing to read the file?

Comment: See also [perldoc -f readline](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html): `while ( ! eof($fh) ) {
         defined( $_ = <$fh> ) or die "readline failed: $!";
         ...
     }`

Comment: You can also test `$filehandle->error` within the loop's body.  See IO::Handle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change your code to work as shown below.

You seem to be using both `STATISTICS` and `$STATISTICS` for your file handle. Since lexical handles are prefereable I have used `$stat` here.

```
open my $stat, "<" . $statisticsFile
    or die "Can't open statistics file $statisticsFile: $!";

until (eof $stat) {
  my $line = <$stat>;
  defined $line or die "Read failure on statistics file $statisticsFile: $!";
  ...
}

close($stat);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, my mistake! Just edited question. Your answer is the right one, since, if you don't test for eof *while reading* the file, you don't get the error, the loop never ends... :-(

Comment: My mistake again, sorry... Loops ends even with the other answers behaviour, but I prefer this approach... It is not even slower...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to test `eof` after the while loop.  If you are not at eof you have an error.  Alternately, and probably safer, check $! since eof *might* reset $!.  Test it either way.

I'll also add that getting an error on read(2) is pretty darn rare.  Perhaps you are running out of memory.

And if you do run out of memory, perl isn't going to be the one who tells you about it, the OS is going to (by killing perl!).

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm non (yet) getting an error, I'm asking just to be on the safe side... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In case of errors the `while` loop breaks because `<STATISTICS>` returns `undef`. `$!` should be set, so you could check the value of `$!` after the loop to see if everything was fine.